# Predict N complementary values

Tags: r, regression

I have a hundred forest sampling areas with approximantely 10 trees each, for which I measured the diameter and mean height. The former is then grouped into three size classes (e.g. 10-20 cm, 20-30, etc).

How can I build a model for new sampling areas with similar heights to predict the abundance of trees in each class (as percentage), knowing that the sum must be 100% ?

(Solutions in R are welcome)

Comment: What information would the predictions be based on?  By "abundance" do you mean total amount (counts, masses, or whatever) of trees in a sampling area, or just proportions?  Would it be possible for your model to work with the actual counts rather than the size classes (so it could be more precise)?  How do you plan to accommodate the likelihood of strong spatial correlation among the values?  What does the "complementary values" in your title refer to?

Comment: "complementary values" refer to the idea of obtaining three values which, summed up, totals to 100...so, basically, the proportion ("abundance") of trees per each size class. No idea yet on how to deal with the spatial correlation. What do you mean with "work with the actual counts rather than the size classes"?